# Discord.NET 1.0 How to Put Commands Into a New .cs File

Tags: c#, command, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to put all of my commands into their own class in their own .cs file. It clutters the file, as the startup and commands are on the same file. It seems that most others had this from the start, but I was not one of them. Here's what I have now:

Startup:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Discord.Commands;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace LockBot__1._0_
{

    public class Program
    {
        private CommandService _commands;
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private IServiceProvider _services;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
            => new Program().StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        public async Task StartAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _commands = new CommandService();

            _services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(_client)
                .AddSingleton(_commands)
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            await InstallCommandsAsync();

            string token = "SomeToken";
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await _client.StartAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        public async Task InstallCommandsAsync()
        {
            _client.Ready += SetGamePlayAsync;
            _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
        }

        private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage messageParam)
        {
            var message = messageParam as SocketUserMessage;
            if (message == null) return;

            int argPos = 0;
            if (!(message.HasCharPrefix('~', ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos))) return;

            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

            var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);
            if (!result.IsSuccess)
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
        }

        public async Task SetGamePlayAsync()
        {
            await _client.SetGameAsync("locksteel.me | ~help");
        }
    }
```

Commands (Shortened):

```
    [Name("Miscellaneous")]
    public class Misc : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        [Command("flip")]
        [Name("flip")]
        [Summary("Flips a coin.")]
        [Alias("coin", "coinflip")]
        public async Task FlipAsync()
        {
            string flipToSend;
            int flip = rand.Next(1, 3);
            if ((flip == 1) && !(flip == 2))
            {
                flipToSend = "Heads.";
            }
            else if ((flip == 2) && !(flip == 1))
            {
                flipToSend = "Tails.";
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("~flip error: error establishing random number");
                return;
            }
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(flipToSend);
            Debug.WriteLine("~flip executed successfully in " + Context.Guild.Name);
        }
    }
```

Note: I'm still fairly new to coding and even moreso to Discord bot making, so please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In my program.cs I am similar to you with:

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Discordbot_Techxas
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private CommandService _commands;
        private IServiceProvider _services;

        public async Task RunBotAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _commands = new CommandService();

            _services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(_client)
                .AddSingleton(_commands)
                .BuildServiceProvider();
            //You need to add the Token for your Discord Bot to the code below.
            string botToken = "YOUR CODE HERE";

            //event subscriptions
            _client.Log += Log;
            _client.UserJoined += AnnounceUserJoined;

            await RegisterCommandsAsync();

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, botToken);

            await _client.StartAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private async Task AnnounceUserJoined(SocketGuildUser user)
        {
            var guild = user.Guild;
            var channel = guild.DefaultChannel;
            await channel.SendMessageAsync($"Welcome, {user.Mention}");
        }

        private Task Log(LogMessage arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
        {
            _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;

            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
        }

        private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
        {
            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;

            if (message is null || message.Author.IsBot) return;

            int argPos = 0;

            if (message.HasStringPrefix("!", ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos))
            {
                var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

                var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);

                if (!result.IsSuccess)
                    Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then each of my command files is activated if based on the following. So !ping goes:

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Discordbot_Techxas.Modules
{
    public class Ping : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("ping")]
        public async Task PingAsync()
        {
            EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();

            builder.WithTitle("Ping!")
                .WithDescription($"PONG back to you {Context.User.Mention} (This will be a never ending game of Ping/Pong)")
                .WithColor(Color.DarkRed);

            await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build());
        }
    }
}
```

After that I just create a new class item in my modules folder for each command I want to tweak. I am new and learning too. But you can see the sandbox bot I am creating and the resources I used to get there at: https://github.com/Thanory/Discordbot_Techxas